# Why is Cuteflow slow on XAMPP 1.7.1?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, xampp

I have recently installed cuteflow (a PHP based document circulation application) on my machine as I need to customize this software. I have XAMPP 1.7.1 running on a windows xp machine on which this application is deployed. While all my other applications that are running on XAMPP are loading fast, only this application is taking exorbitant amount of time.
The same cuteflow application is running very well on my colleagues machines.

Answer (score 1):

Now as you have been running your 'cuteflow' for so long you are certainly interested in more indepth tuning potential. AoMi realtime monitor for LAMPP and WAMPP as well is a PHP/MySQL solution running inside your apache client/server environment.
Over one hundred monitor screens (most of them unique) are available.

In case you are still intersted in XAMPP performance tuning please contact me.

What you will get?

- a zip-file for creating opt/lampp/htdocs/aomi
- three SQL-files for creating tables using phpmyadmin
- installation details just in case

Would like to share my AoMi experience regarding end-to-end-, php-, MySQL-, apache-responsetime with you.

Comment: Why not offer it here? This is a Q&A platform that is supposed to help *everyone*, not only people who contact you by e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP has been known to have many issues with vista and windows 7 including slowing down

Some people in other forum have this solved by editing this

> In
> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
>
> change
>
> `::1             localhost to`
>
> `#::1             localhost`

This is where I got the above solution http://drupal.org/node/206829#comment-1203300

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But I am having windows xp(not vista or windows 7) and my hosts file has only ipadress to localhost mapping. Also, other applications are running fine except this one.